# Pandas converting sub-columns into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

[image]

I have added a picture of my dataframe. There are sub-columns names which are 'GBPEUR=X' 'GBPJPY=X' and 'USDMXN=X'. I would like to take these sub-headings and turn them into different rows. Any idea of how to do this as cant find anything else on the internet? Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
%matplotlib inline

df = yf.Tickers('GBPJPY=X GBPEUR=X USDMXN=X')

currencies = df.history(period='max')
```

Comment: Did you try calling `currencies.stack()`?

Comment: Hero, thanks much apprecited!